using Dilalogflow use own/custom api's to get response
const detectIntent = async (
    projectId,
    sessionId,
    query,
    contexts,
    languageCode
) => {
    // The path to identify the agent that owns the created intent.
    const sessionPath = sessionClient.projectAgentSessionPath(
        projectId,
        sessionId
    );

    // The text query request.
    const request = {
        session: sessionPath,
        queryInput: {
            text: {
                text: query,
                languageCode: languageCode,
            },
        },
    };

    if (contexts && contexts.length > 0) {
        request.queryParams = {
            contexts: contexts,
        };
    }

    const responses = await sessionClient.detectIntent(request);
    return responses[0];
}



const executeQueries = async (projectId, sessionId, queries, languageCode) => {

    // Keeping the context across queries let's us simulate an ongoing conversation with the bot
    let context;
    let intentResponse;
    try {
        console.log(`Sending Query: ${queries}`);
        intentResponse = await detectIntent(
            projectId,
            sessionId,
            queries,
            context,
            languageCode
        );
        console.log('Detected intent');
        console.log(
            `Fulfillment Text: ${JSON.stringify(intentResponse.queryResult)}`

        );


        // Use the context from this response for next queries
        context = intentResponse.queryResult.outputContexts;

        return intentResponse.queryResult.fulfillmentText;


    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }

}


const callIntent = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const response = await executeQueries(projectId, sessionId, req.body.userMessage, languageCode);
        res.status(200).json({ status: true, data: response });
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({
            sucess: false,
            message: error.message
        });
    }

}

I'm working on integrating my Dialogflow agent with my own APIs to fetch dynamic data. Instead of uploading a large number of entities onto Dialogflow, I'd like to retrieve data from my APIs directly. The reason for this is that the data I need is dynamic, and each subsequent response depends on the previous one. If I try to call the APIs in an uneven manner, it might break the flow.
Is there a way for me to extract the name of the entity from Dialogflow so that I can use it to fetch relevant data from my database for further API calls? Any guidance on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated!

Hi ,to extract the name of the entity from Dialogflow you can use client libraby like  python to get entities,can you look at this stack ans  . Let me know if this helps to you or not  .
